# Could not find goal 'copy' in plugin com.heroku.sdk

Tags: java, maven, heroku, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm following this tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) and I'm also trying to use Heroku Maven Plugin. However, there should be something wrong with my **POM.XML** file so the command **mvn package** gives me this:

```
D:\JavaProjects\Again\helloworld>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building helloworld Maven Webapp 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.466 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T23:45:04+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/295M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'copy' in plugin com.heroku.sdk:heroku-maven-plugin:1.1.3 among available goals create-slug, dashboard, deploy, deploy-slug, deploy-war, deploy-war-slug, eclipse-launch-config, release-slug, run-war -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Here is my **POM.XML** below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>helloworld Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
    <plugins>        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>8.5.11.3</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>                        
                        <appName>sushi-dushi</appName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                <pluginExecutions>
                    <!-- copy-dependency plugin -->
                    <pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                            <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <action>
                            <ignore />
                        </action>
                    </pluginExecution>
                </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

So, what am I doing wrong so I can't even build an app with this **POM.XML**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<executions>` section of the `heroku-maven-plugin` is invalid. It should look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I would like to, but when I click the up arrow it gives me: "Thanks for the feedback. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."